# how to add class to font-picker-react in reactJs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

want to add class to font picker react. I tried with simple using class but it was not added.
**version "font-picker-react": "^3.4.1",**

```
import React from "react";
import FontPicker from "font-picker-react";

<FontPicker
          apiKey="AIzaSyCrAmkqacuiyammyv400dq-l6QUNZkoMSE"
          activeFontFamily={this.state.activeFontFamily}
          onChange={(nextFont) =>
            this.setState({
              activeFontFamily: nextFont.family
            })
          }
        />
```

Comment: try with className like this `className="abc1033"`

Comment: tried it but not worked @BhaumikPandhi

Comment: Do you have function based compoment or class-based component? I'm trying with a function-based component. [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rkrmp6?file=src%2FApp.js)